# Installing hadoop on RHEL with Oracle11G

Tags: database, oracle, hadoop, hive

I was wanting to install Hadoop on RHEL 64bit with Oracle 11G already in place. Now once I install hadoop (CDH4) and configure Hive metastore backend to Oracle will my oracle be stored in One node or will it be distributed across nodes..

Could you please clarify me on this.

Thanks and Regards,
Nagashree

Answer (score 0):

The database (Oracle in your case) will be only on one node, but the metastore accessing it can either be embedded, local, or remote. See:

http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera-content/cloudera-docs/CDH4/latest/CDH4-Installation-Guide/cdh4ig_hive_metastore_configure.html